# Accept any large file or request in WCF service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have WCF service. Approx. once a month large XML dump will be uploaded to this service. I don't know yet, how large the files might be (possibly very large).

I get CommunicationException when I want to read received data

> {"The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has
>   been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element."}

```
public void UploadFile(FileUploadMessage request)
{
    //... 
    request.sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
}
```

Now my binding:

```
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpsBinding>
            <binding messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="StreamedRequest" >
```

Now, as I don't know how large uploaded files can get, can I configure my binding to accept requests of any size? Even if I set `maxReceivedMessageSize` to any big number, there might be even larger amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by changing to TCP binding and allowing for up to 10 GB.

```
<services>
    <service >
        <endpoint address="uploadservice" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="UploadService.IUploadService" />

<bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding transferMode="StreamedRequest" maxReceivedMessageSize="10240000000">
```